# Titanic Dataset- Survival Probability (Combined effect of Gender, Age and PClass)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference, chi-squared-test

I have been assigned by my statistics sir to calculate survival probability of Passengers of Titanic by combined effect of Gender, Age and Passenger Class.

I do not understand without Logistic Regression how can I calculate this by only using statistics. If any fellow community member can help me out I will be highly grateful to him/her.

Data:

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you be using logistic regression? I mean you could calculate the probabilities by hand if all predictors were categorical, but age isn't.

Comment: I can't use it because our professor has not taught us regression yet and he wants us to use statistics to get the answer

Comment: This is a bit unclear: regression is a part of statistics. Perhaps you mean descriptive statistics only?
In any case, if you want to do so you will probably need to define categories of age.